# numerical radius of diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

prove that

$w(\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}$)=max($w(A),w(B)$)
i tried using the def of numerical radius

($\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\end{bmatrix})=(\begin{bmatrix}Ax1\\Bx2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\end{bmatrix}$)=
$(Ax1,x1)+(Bx2,x2)$
and then i  took the absolute value I got less than or equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one hand, since
$$
(Ax_1,x_1)+(Bx_2,x_2)
\le w(A)\|x_1\|^2+w(B)\|x_2\|^2
\le\max\left(w(A),w(B)\right)\left(\|x_1\|^2+\|x_2\|^2\right),
$$
we have
$$
w(A\oplus B)
=\max_{\|x_1\|^2+\|x_2\|^2=1}\left[(Ax_1,x_1)+(Bx_2,x_2)\right]
\le\max\left(w(A),w(B)\right).
$$
On the other hand,
$$
w(A\oplus B)
=\max_{\|x_1\|^2+\|x_2\|^2=1}\left[(Ax_1,x_1)+(Bx_2,x_2)\right]
\ge\max_{\|x_1\|=1}(Ax_1,x_1)=w(A)
$$
and likewise $w(A\oplus B)\ge w(B)$. Therefore $w(A\oplus B)\ge\max\left(w(A),w(B)\right)$.

Comment: in the 6th row can you please explain how you take norm x1 to be one after we assume the sum of it and x2 to be 1

Comment: @FarahPalestine $\{(x_1,0):\|x_1\|=1\}\subseteq\{(x_1,x_2):\|x_1\|^2+\|x_2\|^2=1\}$.